# Как конвертировать из PDF в DWG (DXF) с помощью Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, autocad

Интересно. Есть механизм конвертации из ПДФ в DWG или DXF форматы? Естественно средствами Python3.

Comment: Простого готового способа нет. К тому же, pdf может быть векторный или растровый. Если векторный, то его в принципе можно открыть как векторный рисунок (например, через inkscape), и отредактировать как набор линий. Значит теоретически можно как-то перегнать в любой векторный формат, в том числе dwg или dxf. Если растровый - то это уже трассировка, хороший результат получится разве что при идеальных картинках (не сканах).

Comment: А, ну в принципе можно тем же inkscape конвертировать в svg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290006/4752653 . Дальше уже нужно смотреть, теоретически Autocad должен уметь с svg работать (но это не точно)

Comment: В принципе можно считать, что в пдф содержится вектор.